# How to get only first word of object's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan Lucille', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Bat',
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl Dixon', 
        customer_age: 41, 
        customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick Grimes', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County' 
    },
];
```

and I want to separate the `customer_name` into first name and last name, so the first name should stay in `customer_name` and the last name should be placed in newly created property `customer_last_name`. Also I have `newKeys` array which I'm using to replace current keys in `customers` objects like this:

```
const newKeys = [
   'firstname',
   'lastname',
   'age',
   'weapon',
   'email',
   'city'
]

let newCustomers = customers.map(obj => 
    Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur, i) => { 
       acc[newKeys[i]] = cur; 
       return acc; }, {}));
```

and the new array should look like this:

```
customers = [
  {
    firstname: 'Negan',
    lastname: 'Lucille', 
    age: 45, 
    weapon: 'Bat',
    email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
    city: 'Washington' 
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Daryl', 
    lastname: 'Dixon',
    age: 41, 
    weapon: 'Crossbow',
    email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
    city: 'Atlanta' 
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Rick', 
    lastname: 'Grimes',
    age: 45, 
    weapon: 'Magnum 357',
    email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
    city: 'King County' 
  },
]
```

What is the best way to do this? An example will be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend to spell out the new keys explicitly. Much safer and more understandable than this iteration over `Object.values(obj)` and `newKeys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()` to break the name up, add the new properties, then delete the old property.

```js
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan Lucille', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Bat',
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl Dixon', 
        customer_age: 41, 
        customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick Grimes', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County' 
    },
];

const refactored = customers.map(customer=>{
  var [firstname, lastname] = customer.customer_name.split(/\s/);
  return {
    firstname, lastname,
    age: customer.customer_age,
    weapon: customer.customer_weapon,
    email: customer.customer_email,
    city: customer.customer_city
  }
});

console.log(refactored);
```

Comment: Any chance to do this in an immutable way? I still want to have the `customer_name` for the rest of my code. If I use it this way, it will log me the new array, but the page will snap because we deleted `customer_name` from the array

Comment: How's that, @Milos?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Something else was the issue. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first name never has a space in it, you can use [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

You can then use [Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to get the first element and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the rest back together.

For my example I changed the first name to have a last name with 2 words as a demonstration

```js
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan De Lucille', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Bat',
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl Dixon', 
        customer_age: 41, 
        customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick Grimes', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County' 
    },
];

for (const i in customers) {
  const names = customers[i].customer_name.split(" ");
  const newCustomer = {
    age: customers[i].customer_age
    //add in the other properties
  }
  newCustomer.firstname = names.shift();
  newCustomer.lastname = names.join(" ");
  customers[i] = newCustomer;
};

console.log(customers);
```

Comment: Looks great, but how can I use this in my case to populate the `lastname` column with the last name?

Comment: I added a snippet

Comment: Awesome! Any chance to do this on immutable way with deleting the `customer_name` from the object? Because I'm using `customers` array just the way it is on the second part of the page :/

Comment: I have edited my snippet to modify the original array

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I combined your answer with the answer of  @I wrestled a bear once. to get the best of both of them. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const customers = [
    {
        customer_name: 'Negan Lucille', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Bat',
        customer_email: 'negan@sanctuary.com',
        customer_city: 'Washington' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Daryl Dixon', 
        customer_age: 41, 
        customer_weapon: 'Crossbow',
        customer_email: 'daryl.dixon@kickass.com',
        customer_city: 'Atlanta' 
    },
    {
        customer_name: 'Rick Grimes', 
        customer_age: 45, 
        customer_weapon: 'Magnum 357',
        customer_email: 'rick@alexandria.com',
        customer_city: 'King County' 
    },
];

for(let i=0;i<customers.length;i++){
   let name = customers[i].customer_name.split(' ')  
   customers[i].customer_name=name[0]
   customers[i].customer_last=name[1]  
   
   }
   
   console.log(customers)
```

Comment: Note that this does not work if the last name consists of multiple words

Comment: @JannesCarpentier similar for first name. if there are more that 2 "words" in the name these solutions will have issues which have to be resolved by the OPs business logic

Comment: that's true. do you have a better solution?

Comment: In my answer I assumed first name cannot contain a space, since if both first name and last name can contain a space there is not really a way to determine how to split it

Comment: "The Spanish artist was born Salvador Felipe Jacinto Dalí y Domenech. Following the Spanish tradition" :D

Comment: Those are multiple first names. I cannot think of a first name that contains a space, as they are mostly written using a `-`, but last names of multiple words are very common